# Paste param {id} in controller from route Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route:

```
Route::get('/{id?}/{post}', 'PostController@show')->name('postshow');
```

I can paste param `{id}` from controller?

```
public function showPost($id = null, Post $post)
{
    $id = $post->id;
    return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```

I need when user go to post, I need url of post will be: `http://example.com/12345/post-slug`

Now I get: `http://example.com/post-slug`

I know that I can pass id in route: `route('postshow', [$post->id, $post]);`
But I can't, because in blade I have 1000+ records like this: `route('postshow', $post);` And search and edit every blade file I can't.

Comment: What is the question btw?

Answer (score 0):

As per your below route :

`Route::get('/{id?}/{slug}', 'PostController@show')->name('postshow');`

And in the controller(not sure how you want it but as per my understanding of your question :

```
public function showPost($id = null, $slug)
{
    if($id){
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    }
    else{
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    }

    return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```

In blade, if you want to generate this url :

```
route('postshow', [ 'id' => $post->id, , 'slug' => $post->slug]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the old route to the new one like this:

```
Route::get('/{post}', function(Post $post) {
    return redirect($post->id . "/" . $post->slug );
});
Route::get('/{id?}/{post}', 'PostController@show')->name('postshow');
```

This will redirect your old request of `http://example.com/post-slug` to `http://example.com/12345/post-slug`